# .htaccess limit file to script access

Tags: .htaccess, file

I am extremely new to the concept of .htaccess, and I wanted to know how I could use it to allow a file to be used on a script on a .html file in the same directory as the .htaccess and the file. However, if you try to navigate to the file instead of viewing the script on the .html file, I would like it to be blocked. Thanks!

Update: Please see below comments!

Update 2: It seems that there is no way to achieve what I wished. That's ok, though. I just used a bunch of obfustication, and that seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to restrict access to a (script)file using htaccess so that a visitor can't directly link to the script file. Assuming this is working like described the visitor would load the HTML-file, the HTML-file would render and request the scriptfile....which will be blocked. So this isn't the way to go I reckon.

I would suggest changing the HTML-file to PHP when possible and include the script with a php include/require. This way the server-side code will determine what content is served.

Once you're including the file server-side you can prevent direct access to the file using htaccess by placing the code below inside your htaccess:

```
#Prevent Users From Accessing .inc* files in .htaccess
<Files ~ ".inc">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

In the above example direct access to .inc-files will be denied. Change this file-extension to your needs.

Inside your index.php file you'll need to include the file containing your script with something like:

```
include 'filewithscript.inc';
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: All right. I changed it to php. How would I do this include/require thing while restricting direct access to the file?

Comment: Another note: this is a javascript file.

Comment: It did work for including the script, however, I don't want it to just show the text. In html, I would have something like <script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js"></script>. However, when I do the command: include 'filewithscript.inc'; It just shows the code text on the website, which destroys the original purpose. :(

Comment: Also, it was in a canvas tag if that changes anything. It has visual elements.

Comment: Basically, it shows the js file's code on the website instead of executing it in a canvas.

Comment: And I wish that it includes the script file without allowing direct access to the script itself.